# Activated ability of Golden Guardian

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can the ability of [Golden Guardian](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGolden%20Guardian%5d) be activated at any time? Say, during another player's turn or during an attacker's or blockers fast effects phase?

Comment: Yes. ([116.1b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Timing_and_priority)).  Can you describe why you think you *wouldn't* be able to activate this ability at those times?

Comment: What is an "attacker's or blocker's fast effects phase"? Do you mean the point after attackers or blockers are declared where their abilities go on the stack and players can cast spells? (That is not a phase, and it is not called a fast effects phase.)

Comment: "fast effects" apparently is something from Yu-Gi-Oh. I guess they mean after declaring attackers and/or blockers

Comment: ["Fast effects"](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Fast_effects) is an obsolete Magic: the Gathering term, and I can see why it would be confusing for someone who played in that era.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, activated abilities can by activated at any time you have priority, unless the ability states otherwise, which is not the case with [Golden Guardian](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGolden%20Guardian%5d). This is per Comprehensive Rules:

> **112.3b** Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]” **A player may activate such an ability whenever they have priority.** (...)